# How to select a datetime index range and use if conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, if-statement

I have a data frame `df` with 100,000 rows using DateTime index.  Let the January case as an example. I would like to create a new column named `'Experiment'`, which may help me to identify when the experiment starts and ends, with 10 experiments in total.

```
 df=
                            Place      
        Time               
        2021-01-01 00:00    home         
        2021-01-01 00:01    home       
        2021-01-01 00:02    home        
        2021-01-01 00:03    home     
        ................    ....  
        ................    ....
        2021-01-31 23:57    home
        2021-01-31 23:58    home
        2021-01-31 23:59    home
```

For example, experiment A starts between `2021-01-01 00:00 and 2021-01-01 00:02` and experiment J starts between `2021-01-31 23:57 and 2021-01-31 23:59`.  the expected results will be like this.

```
df=
                            Place  Experiment
        Time               
        2021-01-01 00:00    home      A   
        2021-01-01 00:01    home      A 
        2021-01-01 00:02    home      A  
        2021-01-01 00:03    home     
        ................    ....  
        ................    ....
        2021-01-31 23:57    home      J
        2021-01-31 23:58    home      J
        2021-01-31 23:59    home      J
```

My approach is like this.

```
df["experiment"] = ""
df["experiment"] = np.where(df.between_time('2021-01-01 00:00','2021-01-01 00:02'),'A',np.nan)
df["experiment"] = np.where(df.between_time('2021-01-31 23:57','2021-01-31 23:59'),'J',np.nan)
```

And I just realise that the `between_time` is not working when includes date. Moreover, I am facing the problem that `the Length of values does not match length of index.`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.where` as you do right now would override what you already created.

For multiple conditions, use `.loc` to update:

```
# the experiment time
list_starts = ['2021-01-01 00:00','2021-01-31 23:57']
list_ends = ['2021-01-01 00:02', '2021-01-31 23:59']
list_names = ['A','J']

for start_time, end_time, name in zip(list_starts, list_ends, list_names):
    df.loc[start_time:end_time, 'experiment'] = name
```

Another (better) way to organize your experiment time can be:

```
# name: (start, end)
exp_times = {
    'A': ('2021-01-01 00:00', '2021-01-01 00:02'),
    'J': ('2021-01-31 23:57', '2021-01-31 23:59')
}

for name, (start_time, end_time) in exp_times.items():
    df.loc[start_time:end_time, 'experiment'] = name
```

Output:

```
                    Place experiment
Time                                
2021-01-01 00:00:00  home          A
2021-01-01 00:01:00  home          A
2021-01-01 00:02:00  home          A
2021-01-01 00:03:00  home        NaN
2021-01-31 23:57:00  home          J
2021-01-31 23:58:00  home          J
2021-01-31 23:59:00  home          J
```

**Note:** As you may have noticed, you can use strings to slice/index a time-indexed dataframe.

Comment: Thank you! The first way is not working for me but the second way is working. Btw, your answer of the first way has missed the 's' for the list_end and list_name

Comment: @ahsojai thanks, updated the answer. I think the two solutions are different by only how you organize the data. But I'm glad that at least one of them works for you.